How to deploy only the changes to a profile instead of the whole profile?
Our organization uses DevOps Center for deployment activities. Most of the profiles have different configurations across prod and the dev envs. There is no option in DevOps Center to deploy just the changes instead of the whole profile, which causes the profile in prod to be overwritten.
What is the best and easiest way to achieve this requirement? Manual changes is not possible because of the vast number of changes. The goal here is to add minimal additional deployment steps.

You will have to use a more powerful devops tool (like Copado, Gearset, etc.) that  allows you to select specific changes in perm sets and profiles for deployment.

Our company switched to devops center from copado as cost cutting. Is there any other way to do it without having to use premium tools?

I doubt there is another free tool available to do this.
